# Gradient Descent with derivative constraints

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

I am trying to solve an optimization problem:

Find a parameter vector $\theta$ so that $\sum_x \log f(\theta, x) \cdot y$ is minimized (it's a probability problem), subject to $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(\theta, x) \leq C$ for all $x$ in the input space.

My problem is that estimating the derivative of $f$ at a point $x$ is expensive, and my input space is really, really, really big.  In fact, just computing $f(\theta, x)$ on some "fine" grid across my input space would be prohibitively expensive.  Are there some handy theorems that may be of use here (even if they are only applicable to certain classes of functions)?

Comment: Do you know [Kriging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging?wprov=sfti1)?

Comment: I've done gaussian process regression before, and it was very slow for even small input spaces.  Also, I think it would require me to, at a minimum, compute $f(\theta, x)$ on a "fine" grid across my input space, where "fine" is determined by the maximum size of some order of derivative.... but I don't know that maximum size.  :)

Comment: I don’t have much experience with kriging. It might be very slow. Do you mean grid as a regular grid? It don’t think that it is necessary. With every approximative methods you can chose tolerance heuristically only.